# How to get code window to update based on current branch in terminal?

Tags: git, pycharm, git-bash

**Context:** I am a noob. COMPLETELY.

I have been doing little class projects using PyCharm (for math classes, I'm not a developer). Literally just typing code and hitting the green "play" button to run the code.

Now I'm graduated working on job interviews and trying to get smart. I actually have some "developer" type interviews coming up, which is crazy cause I'm a programming dummy. And they must know this based on my resume. Anyway... I'm trying to fix that. I learned about Git and version control today. I got inspired, downloaded Git, figured out how to have Git's shell imbedded in PyCharm.

Then, I learned about "branches" which seems particularly useful aspect of this whole git thing. So I created a "develop" branch and learned the commands to switch back and forth between the "master" and "develop" branch.

**Now the problem:** In the youtube video where all this is taught, the narrators text editor updates based on which branch he has navigated to on his command line. Mine does not. I don't think this is very fair and I want to cry. The knowledge of how to make this happen might stem the rising tide of my shame at being so lost.

Comment: So your problem is, your code doesn't change after switching to another branch?

Comment: @NadineFisch Bingo! Also, I see a little pane in the bottom right hand corner that supposedly shows all my branches. It only shows the master, while my embedded terminal shows both.

Comment: Which editor do you use? With

Comment: Are you really on the new branch? Maybe you have merge conflicts. Olease try git branch. The branch with te star flagged is the current one

Comment: @NadineFisch I'm using PyCharm, and I've checked using the command "git branch" to see which branch I'm currently on. I moved to the "develop" branch by typing "git checkout develop", then made some small changes to comments. I then switched back using "git checkout master" and those changes I made to the "develop" branch are still showing.

Comment: @NadineFisch It has begun working. It takes about 10 seconds for the window to update. I guess I was just impatient. Thank you.

Comment: @NadineFisch Concision at its best. Impressive.